# Write to file upon button press

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Trying to write to a txt file upon button click. Not sure how to do it and my code isnt working. Im starting to think i might need AJAX? If so, can someone give me a quick pointer in the right direction? Please and thankyou in advance!

Here's my code:

```
<?php
 //write to file on button event

function buttonWrite()
{
$filename = 'button.txt';
@ $fp = fopen("messages/".$filename, 'wb');
if (!$fp)
{
    echo '<p><strong>Cannot generate message file</strong></p></body></html>';
    exit;
} 

$outputstring  = 'Hello, i have been generated by the button';

fwrite($fp, $outputstring);
}

?>

<html>

<head>
<title>Button Writer</title>
</head>

<body>
<button type="button" onclick="buttonWrite()">Write to File</button>
</body>

</html>
```

UPDATE!
None of these answers actually work at all.. Not sure if its the server im hosting on or what, but yeah the just dont work.. any ideas guys ?

Comment: Ps. Im entirely new to AJAX.. so please dont make it too difficult

Comment: You cannot call a PHP-function from the HTML. You need to, as you said, make an AJAX call to the php-file, which will in turn excecute the code.

Comment: JavaScript is front-end script, so it can not access files on your server; so yes, you do need ajax call to php script, that will do the job for you. Here is a starter for you: http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/

Comment: jQuery ajax has always been the easiest way to implement ajax functionality, you could refer this official jquery link ,http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a **PHP file** .Lets say "abc.php".It contains:

```
<?PHP
$filename = 'button.txt';
@ $fp = fopen("messages/".$filename, 'wb');
if (!$fp)
{
    echo '<p><strong>Cannot generate message file</strong></p></body></html>';
    exit;
} 
else
{
$outputstring  = 'Hello, i have been generated by the button';
fwrite($fp, $outputstring);
Echo "Message inserted";
}
?>
```

**HTML file**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Button Writer</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
<button id="button1" type="button">Write to File</button>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#button1').click(function(){
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "abc.php",
 data: "",
 success: function(msg){
     alert(msg);
 },
 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Some error occured");
 }
 });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Entire Code

Save.php

```
 <?php
         //write to file on button event

        function buttonWrite()
        {
        $filename = 'button.txt';
        $outputstring = "Hello, i have been generated by the button'\n";
        file_put_contents($filename, $outputstring, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        }

        ?>
```

index.php or index.html

```
    <html>

        <head>

        </head>

        <body>
<form name="input" action="save.php">
<input type="submit" value="Write to File">
</form>

        </html>
```

This should work it will write the $outputstring to the button.txt using the file_put_contents function

Comment: And where is js function on click callback described?

Comment: So where do i put the file_put_contents?

Comment: I swear to christ theres something up with the server or something because i press the button and literaly nothing happens! :(

Comment: Wait you need java installed for this to run right ? Because im on a mates PC, and it doesnt have java, i just realised.. Could that be it ?

Comment: i changed it to basically use HTML submit button could you try that?

Comment: Wait, it worked like that! I just need it to do this without posing to a new page or even refreshing the page.. can we do that now ?

Comment: ok lets create an iframe place this under the </form> <iframe width="DEFINEWIDTH"  frameBorder="0" height="DEFINEHEIGHT" name="my_iframe" scrolling="yes" ></iframe> change the width and height to what you want than after action="save.php" add target="my_iframe"

Answer (score 1):

You do it wrong - javascript and php can't be executed together in HTML.
What you need to do is to create:

1) "onclick" button event, that execute AJAX request to your server. I'll use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in my examples for the simplicity.

```
<button id="btn">SAVE FILE</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // bind click event to button
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    // send ajax request to save.php (using POST method)
    $.post('save.php', { text: "sample text", function(data) { 
      // output response to console
      console.log(data); 
    });
  });
</script>
```

2) create save.php file - it will be responsible for saving your data to the file

```
<?php 
  // saving sample text to file (it doesn't include validation!)
  file_put_contents('file.txt', $_POST['text']);

  die('file has been saved');
?>
```

Comment: Doesnt work? Any idea's why? Will i need to change permissions on the server\

Comment: Nothing.. Im not on my main PC so i cant run WAMP, therefore im FTPing to a server and running it directly.. So no errors, however i click the button and the DIE message isnt even executing, suggesting its not making it that far